# 220v Grid Tie Inverter

Tags: safety

I just bought a 3000w 220v grid tie inverter and I'm wondering if it is safe to simply plug it into the 220v port in my laundry room (the one my dryer runs on) and then run it, or is there more I need to know.

Comment: This is one of those questions where if you have to ask here, you really should be talking to an electrician who's qualified to work in your area. Especially since you haven't told us anything about who you are or where you're located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody on this site can tell you that it's OK, especially with the lack of information you've provided, but I can tell you that a safe grid tie inverter must have at a minimum:

- Proper over-current prevention. This means a fuse or breaker sized to the **lowest rated item in the current path**. Do not just select a fuse size based on the inverter. If you're doing a grid-tie system by plugging into an existing outlet than your household circuit breakers probably cover the AC side, but you absolutely need a fuse or breaker on the DC side.
- A grid-tie inverter must automatically detach / depower if the mains power goes out. This prevents the dead lines from becoming electrified, which may injure someone working on or near the lines. The inverter may do this itself, but you must be sure.
- Proper outdoor / weatherproofing for any wires that run outside (e.g. to a solar panel). This means using outdoor-rated cable, fasteners, etc.

3000 watts is a lot of energy, so make sure you do this right. That's easily enough power to kill someone and/or start a fire.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Henry, I will definitely keep this in mind. Good advice!